# How can we enable user's thumbnails on their drupal content?

Tags: drupal-6

I am going on making a Drupal site matches with my requirement. A requirement describes that on each node, such as Blog or Forum, except publisher's name and published date below the node's title, should show the user's thumbnail (similar to avatar in Facebook or Twitter) too.

I thing there is an existing module for this requirement. but I couldn't find it.

Could you tell me how to do this? some guideline or link to an example? it would be nice if you can tell me the module that is able to do this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wany to enable picture support: http://drupal.org/node/22271

and in addition, you probaly want to change the theme to call

```
theme('user_picture', $account);
```

where you want to display the picture (where `$account` is the account object of the user that is posting the node/comment)

the corresponding template file is [user-picture.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/file/modules/user/user-picture.tpl.php)